# How to Track AdSense Abusive Traffic in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense, web-traffic

My website has received some direct traffic from USA New York, which has 79 Users with 83 Sessions and it caused 307 Ads clicks of US$2k+ in revenue with 389 page views.

**90% of the revenue is from "High-End Mobile Devices".**
In the attached picture; we can see only 5 sessions of users of Huawei phones made over $700. Is this normal?
[image]

How can I filter my traffic and block the spam traffic behind this?
Is it possible to see user IP from Analytics to block them?

Comment: Is it bot traffic or actual users? The former probably won't get recorded in GA.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It appears to be actual human traffic because the bounce rate seems normal. Also, I checked AdSense stats in Google Analytics GEO>Location and it shows New York Users AdSense CTR is 245%.